# Paging - address space

Tags: paging

Paging in some processor allows to associate virtual memory adress (823C5678)_16 on physical adress (A2365678)_16, but does not allow to associate virtual adress (2ABD678)_16 to physical adress (34D678)_16. What can be said about virtual memory and physical memory's adress space? Please explain, what is going on? I have no inkling about it.

Comment: This sounds very much like homework or an exam question in its current form. ("some processor", "What can be said about" etc.). An interesting question, none the less.

Comment: It is past exam question. The exact information about what processor is it is not needed.